# Negamax-search implementation not working when player can move twice in a row

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, minimax, negamax

I'm trying to implement Negamax search for a game called [Nine Men's Morris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Men%27s_Morris) in Java.

If a player has three pieces in a row (here called a mill), he removes a opponent's piece (the 'additional' move) before switching turns.

Additionally, there is a *set piece* phase and a *move piece* phase, after all initial pieces have been placed.

My implementation looks like this:

```
public int[] negamaxSet(int depth, int alpha, int beta, int color) {
    if (depth == 0 || board.isGameOver()) {
        return new int[] { color *  evaluateBoard(color};
    }

    int stonesSet = color == -1 ? board.blackStonesSet : board.whiteStonesSet;
    // set piece phase
    if (stonesSet < Game.initialPieces) {
        List<Piece> moves = board.getEmpty();

        int bestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int bestMoveX = -1;
        int bestMoveY = -1;

        for (Piece piece : moves) {
            Piece move = new Piece(color, piece.x, piece.y);
            board.setPiece(move);

            int value[] = null;

            //Player made Mill, move again
            if(board.checkMill(move)){
                value = negamaxRemove(depth - 1, alpha, beta, color);               
            }
            //normal move, switch turn
            else {
                value = negamaxSet(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha, -color);
                value[0] = -value[0];
            }
            if (value[0] > bestValue) {
                bestValue = value[0];
                bestMoveX = move.x;
                bestMoveY = move.y;
            }
            if (value[0] > alpha) {
                alpha = value[0];
            }

            board.revertLastMove();

    //      if (alpha >= beta)
    //          break;
        }
        return new int[] { bestValue, bestMoveX, bestMoveY };
    } else {

        //move phase

        List<Piece>  moves = board.getPiecesByColor(color); 

        int bestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int bestMoveX = -1;
        int bestMoveY = -1;
        int bestMoveX2 = -1;
        int bestMoveY2 = -1;

        for (Piece piece : moves) {

            List<Piece> adjPieces = board.getAdjacentEmtpy(piece);
            for(Piece adjPiece : adjPieces){

                Piece newFrom = new Piece(color, piece.x, piece.y);
                Piece newTo = new Piece(color, adjPiece.x, adjPiece.y);

                board.movePiece(newFrom, newTo);

                int[] value = null;

                //Player made Mill, move again

                if(board.checkMill(newTo, false)){
                    value = negamaxRemove(depth - 1, alpha, beta, color);

                } else {
                    value = negamaxSet(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha, -color);
                    value[0] = -value[0];
                }

                if (value[0] > bestValue) {
                    bestValue = value[0];
                    bestMoveX = newFrom.x;
                    bestMoveY = newFrom.y;
                    bestMoveX2 = newTo.x;
                    bestMoveY2 = newTo.y;
                }
                if (value[0] > alpha) {
                    alpha = value[0];
                }

                board.revertLastMove();

    //          if (alpha >= beta)
    //              break;

            }


        }
        return new int[] { bestValue, bestMoveX, bestMoveY, bestMoveX2, bestMoveY2 };       
    }
}
```

It is probably advisable to not change the basic Negamax algorithm and encapsulate setting a stone and moving a stone in one operation to not distinguish between the two in the algorithm itself, but from my understanding it *should* still work like this.

The function negamaxRemove is basically the same as negamaxSet but without checking for a mill (not possible) and looking for a piece to remove.

Is it correct to call negamaxRemove with the same parameters as the calling function and not switching the sign (thereby maximizing again)?

Somehow the AI player does not prevent the opponent from forming a mill (but forms one himself if possible).

Is the algorithm correct like this and I should look for the error elsewhere in the code?
Or did I misinterpreted how Negamax should work?
(I commented out alpha-beta pruning so setting alpha or beta wrongly wouldn't make a difference here)

I would really appreciate some pointers!

Comment: How does `evaluateBoard` work?. You shouldn't have to multiply by color - the score should be always relative to current player. You really should treat double move as one, it will save you a lot of unnecessary trouble.

Comment: You could be right.
I took wikipedia's pseudo code as reference where it is multiplied by color, but maybe there it was only done to get the score relative to the current player and nothing more... which is already done with the parameter in my evaluateBoard-method.
I will test it in a minute.


How would you treat setting/moving a piece and then (conditionally) remove a stone without invoking a recursive function to choose the best piece to remove?

Comment: Just add another loop. I.e.: if move completes row, iterate also over oponents pieces to select which one to remove. Or add it directly to list of possible moves: 0, 3, (4, remove 1), (4, remove 2)... It would allow you to use generic search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

[I've implemented this game](https://github.com/NickLarsen/game-frame/blob/master/src/game-frame/Games/NineMensMorrisGameRules.cs#L290).  Change your definition of a move from "performs action, awarded another move" to "performs multipart action".  Then instead of having to make 2 "moves", you just end up with moves looking like `from: 3, to: 0, remove: 17`, `from: 3, to: 0, remove 19`, etc.  For moves that do not remove a piece, you simply set remove to `-1`.